# JsonException: Cycle detected when using PostMan

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, postman, web-api-testing

When I post my object

```
    {
    "Title": "LookingForGroup",
    "Description": "Descrptjasag",
    "CreatorName":"thelo@mail.bg",
    "Price":"4"
    }
```

in postman , I get a json exception that says :

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected
>   which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the
>   object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.

My Post Class

```
public class Post


     {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public ApplicationUser Creator { get; set; }
            public string CreatorId { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public PostType PostType { get; set; }
            public decimal Price { get; set; }
            public ICollection<Bid> Bids { get; set; }

        }
```

My Model

```
public class PostInputModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string CreatorName { get; set; }
    }
```

My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<PostInputModel>> PostPost(PostInputModel input)
        {
            Post post = new Post()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Title = input.Title,
                Creator = _context.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == input.CreatorName).FirstOrDefault(),
                Description = input.Description,
                PostType = PostType.Help,
                Price = 4

            };
            _context.Posts.Add(post);
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (PostExists(post.Id))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return CreatedAtAction("GetPost", post);
        }
```

My User Class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ICollection<Bid> Bids { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Post> FreelanceService { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Do a break point after "public async Task<ActionResult<PostInputModel>> PostPost(PostInputModel input)" to see what "input" is bringing in. This will help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I assume that in your User model you have collection of posts and post has reference to user. So JSON serializer tries to serialize user and his posts and for each post serialize user in infinite loop. Please provide your User model.

Comment: I did something else . Removed the context add part and only left the new object and return parts. It returned a rather normal object without any errors.

Comment: @Wokuo I'll edit in a second.

Answer (score 0):

You have circular reference in your model: Post has an ApplicationUser, that has a collection of Post's. That's your problem! Use foreign keys so you can relate posts with users, without creating circular references. Create and ApplicationUserId, replace in Post model, and use it as a key. [1](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/41288#issuecomment-534648397)

> JsonSerializer in .NET Core 3.0 does not support circular references. A proposal to support this is being worked on in #41002.
>   If you believe this is not a cycle and instead you just have a very deep heirarchy, you can set JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth to something larger than the default.

Comment: I updated my post so it has my User class in it. I actually found out that the api data save is working , my database is being filled with data from postman. But still it gives me this error after I click post.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25119788)

Comment: @Toodoo okay. Edited my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comment I am assume your JsonSerializer goes into infinite loops, because of reference between user and posts. Every user contains posts and every post contains user. You can easily check that by using QuickWatch in debug mode.

You will get something like that

```
User
  Post1
  Post2
    User
      Post1
      Post2
       ..
```

Generally it's not a good practice to return your EntityFramework models as result object. You should create DTO objects that will be returned instead of EF objects:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5
Your DTO objects shouldn't contains references that leads to this infinite loop.

Other solution that I personally would not use is to inform serializer to dont serialize specific properties:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ICollection<Bid> Bids { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ICollection<Post> FreelanceService { get; set; }
}
```

If JsonIgnore attribute will not help, please try to use [IgnoreDataMember].